# Matrix Template Library matrix inversion

Tags: c++, math, stl, boost, linear-algebra

I'm trying to inverse a matrix with version Boost boost_1_37_0 and MTL mtl4-alpha-1-r6418. I can't seem to locate the matrix inversion code. I've googled for examples and they seem to reference lu.h that seems to be missing in the above release(s). Any hints?

[@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8643/matt-cruikshank) suggested copying lu.h, but that seems to be from MTL2 rather than MTL4. I'm having trouble compiling with MTL2 with VS05 or higher.

So, any idea how to do a matrix inversion in MTL4?

Update: I think I understand Matt better and I'm heading down [this ITL path](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/itl/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you use `lu_factor`, and then `lu_inverse`.  I don't remember what you have to do with the pivots, though.  From the [documentation](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/reference/html/index.html).

And yeah, like you said, it looks like their documentations says you need lu.h, somehow:

> **How do I invert a matrix?**
>
> The first question you should ask
>   yourself is whether you want to really
>   compute the inverse of a matrix or if
>   you really want to solve a linear
>   system. For solving a linear system of
>   equations, it is not necessary to
>   explicitly compute the matrix inverse.
>   Rather, it is more efficient to
>   compute triangular factors of the
>   matrix and then perform forward and
>   backward triangular solves with the
>   factors. More about solving linear
>   systems is given below. If you really
>   want to invert a matrix, there is a
>   function `lu_inverse()` in mtl/lu.h.

If nothing else, you can look at [lu.h on their site](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/mtl/lu.h).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm in the middle of that trying to make/port lu.h I found, but it seems to be a different version and my linear al is quite rusty.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used boost or MTL for matrix math but I have used JAMA/[TNT](http://math.nist.gov/tnt/).

This page http://wiki.cs.princeton.edu/index.php/TNT shows how to take a matrix inverse. The basic method is library-independent:

1. factor matrix M into XY where X and Y are appropriate factorizations (LU would be OK but for numerical stability I would think you would want to use QR or maybe SVD).
2. solve I = MN = (XY)N for N with the prerequisite that M has been factored; the library should have a routine for this.

Answer (score 0):

In MTL4 use this:

```
mtl::matrix::inv(Matrix const &A, MatrixOut &Inv);
```

Here is a link to the [api](http://www.simunova.com/docs/mtl4/html/namespacemtl_1_1matrix.html#aef7c70cf9677d4995c973adcf408a531).